# Delete couchDB databases

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

Is there a way to delete multiple databases in Futon? Instead of creating multiple documents in one database, by mistake I ran erlang query and created about 3000 databases. Can I delete them in bulk all together? Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't do this in bulk with Futon.

However, if you have access to the server itself via SSH, you can simply delete the database files in `/var/lib/couchdb/`.